# create an empty Pygame window..

Tags: python, pygame

**The code is this**

```
import sys
import pygame

def run_game():

    # Initialize game and create a screen object.
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    # Start the main loop for the game.

    while True:

        # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

                sys.exit()
        # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
        pygame.display.flip()
run_game()
```

**The error is this**

line 2, import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Comment: you need to install pygame.

Comment: `pygame` is not standard module - you have to use `pip install pygame` to install it first. More in [official documentation](http://pygame.org/docs/)

Comment: I have already installed it. It was successfully installed but it's just not importing

Comment: what system do you use ? what command did you use to install ? did you get error message during installation ? do you have two pythons installed ? do you use PyCharm or other IDE ?

Comment: I use 64 bit windows 7. No I didnt get any message in this version(32 bit). but it did in amd_64 bit file

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you used *pip* to install the PyGame package you should be able to use the command *pip show pygame* to show you information about this package.  That should show a "Location:" field.

Then load up your Python interpreter and try the following:

```
>>> import sys
>>> '{{Paste in path from Location: as shown above}}' in sys.path
```

If that returns "False" then you'd found the issue.  Add the PyGame location to your PYTHONPATH environment setting, or add a *sys.path.append(...)* to the code you want to write using the library, or resolve the path inclusion issue in some other way.

Note: it's probably best for you to consider using [virtual environment best practices](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) in order to more effectively managed your libraries and other package dependencies on a per project basis.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you used pip to install the PyGame package, you should be able to use the command pip show pygame to show you information about this package. That should display a "Location:" field.

Then, load up your Python interpreter and try the following:

```
import sys
'{{Paste in path from Location: as shown above}}' in sys.path
If that returns "False," then you have found the issue. You can add the PyGame location to your PYTHONPATH environment setting or add a sys.path.append(...) to the code where you want to use the library. Alternatively, you can resolve the path inclusion issue in some other way.
```

Note: It's recommended to follow virtual environment best practices to more effectively manage your libraries and other package dependencies on a per-project basis.